# dismissing keyboard with no reference to text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard

I have a UITableView with some cells that have UITextFields in them. If I begin editing cell #1 then scroll down so that it off screen, then try to dismiss the keyboard with `[self.view endEditing:YES]` the keyboard will remain on screen.

I believe this is because the uitextfield no longer exists and therefore technically nothing is "editing".

This seems logical because when I scroll back up so that cell #1 is visible it is not editing anymore because it was deallocated/reused.

Is there a way I can actually dismiss the keyboard? Or is there a way I could dismiss the keyboard when the cell goes offscreen?

Below is some example code, I'm not sure how useful it will be though...

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
       CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
       float fractionalPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
       NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
       self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

       if (self.page != page) {
           //dismiss keyboard when page changes
           self.page = page;
           [self.view endEditing:YES];
       }
   }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if(indexPath.row == kIndexOfItemID) {

            HMFItemIDCell *itemIDCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HMFItemIDCell"];

            [itemIDCell setupCellWithBlock:^(NSString *string) {
                self.mutableItem.itemID = string;
            }];

            //Adjust Font to match iOS 7
            itemIDCell.customLabel.text = @" Item ID";
            itemIDCell.customLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:17];

            self.idField = itemIDCell.customTextField;

            itemIDCell.customLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

            self.idField.text = self.mutableItem.itemID;
            self.idField.delegate = self;
            self.idField.tag = kIDTextField;

            itemIDCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            return itemIDCell;

    } //... other cells are setup basically the same way.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily have a property for `UITextField`, and by use of `UITextField` delegate methods, you can get the reference of `UITextField`.

Define a property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)UITextField *lastSelectedField;
```

In the delegates of `UITextField` handle this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.lastSelectedField=textField;
    return YES;
}
```

The delegate above will get called if you set the delegate for the textfield.

Now you have the reference, use it to resign anywhere.

```
if (self.page != page) {
    //dismiss keyboard when page changes
    self.page = page;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
   [self.lastSelectedField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Done. Cheers.

Comment: I tried this idea. If I choose a text field then scroll up and down a couple times (to remove it from memory) then try to resignFirstResponder nothing happens.

Comment: @Hackmodford The solution should work, I suspect if(self.page != page) condition is failing. If we put it directly without any condition it should work.

Comment: No the condition was working. In any case I solved the problem by simply dismissing the keyboard if anything is scrolled.